# S3 Lifecycle Configuration with filters using PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I need to configure the AWS S3 Lifecycle management policy that moves all backups that contain an object tag with the key “Virginia” and its value is “True” to AWS Glacier after 60 days. I have following PowerShell script and the part that I need help is how to filter using object tag and it’s value.

```
$LifecycleTransition = New-object Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleTransition
$LifecycleTransition.Days = 60
$LifecycleTransition.StorageClass = ‘Glacier’

$LifecycleRule = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleRule
$LifecycleRule.Id = “Glacier60Days”
$LifecycleRule.Transition = $LifecycleTransition
$LifecycleRule.Prefix = $null
$LifecycleRule.Filter =????

$LifecycleRule.Status = “Enabled”
Write-S3LifecycleConfiguration -BucketName mybucketname - 
Configuration_Rules $LifecycleRule
```

Answer (score 0):

I am finding it hard to do it with PowerShell, still working on it - defining Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleFilterPredicate seems to be tricky via .NET class. In the meantime, if awscli is something you can work with, here is the method which can take a json file with config as input:

1. Create and save below config into a json file:

   {
       "Rules": [
           {
               "Expiration": {
                   "Days": 50
               },
               "ID": "remove-60-days",
               "Filter": {
                   "And": {
                       "Prefix": "py",
                       "Tags": [
                           {
                               "Key": "non-use",
                               "Value": "yes"
                           },
                           {
                               "Key": "raj",
                               "Value": "false"
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               },
               "Status": "Enabled"
           },
           {
               "Expiration": {
                   "Days": 26
               },
               "ID": "do-nothing-in-20-days",
               "Filter": {
                   "And": {
                       "Prefix": "java",
                       "Tags": [
                           {
                               "Key": "jadoo",
                               "Value": "nagri"
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               },
               "Status": "Enabled",
               "Transitions": [
                   {
                       "Days": 20,
                       "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }

Here, there are 2 rules. One of them is simply removing and other is sending to glacier - both the rules use tags as well as prefix for your example needs

2. Now, use below CLI with the input json file:

   aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test-bla --lifecycle-configuration file://config.json

This should assign the given config to the bucket 'test-bla'
I hope this helps.

Reference [put-bucket-lifecycleconfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration.html)

-- [Edit] --
Ok - here is PowerShell:

```
#Create the rule filter object
$NewRule=[Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleRule]::new()
$NewRule.Id = "Test-From-Write-cmdlet-1"

#Create rule expiration
$NewRuleExpiration = [Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleRuleExpiration]::new()
$NewRuleExpiration.Days = 50
$NewRule.Expiration = $NewRuleExpiration

$NewRule.Status = [Amazon.S3.LifecycleRuleStatus]::Enabled

#create filter with prefix 'and' tags
$AndOperand=[Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleAndOperator]::new()
$operands = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleFilterPredicate]]::new()

#create filters to add to AndOperand
$PrefixFilter = [Amazon.S3.Model.LifecyclePrefixPredicate]@{"Prefix"=  "py"}

$TagFilter = [Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleTagPredicate]@{"Tag" = @{"Key" = "non-use";"Value"="yes"}}

#You can add more filters into operands 
$operands = @($PrefixFilter, $TagFilter)

#create new filter
$NewLifecycleFilter = [Amazon.S3.Model.LifecycleFilter]::new()
$NewRule.Filter = $NewLifecycleFilter
$NewLifecycleFilter.LifecycleFilterPredicate = $AndOperand
$NewRule.Filter.LifecycleFilterPredicate.Operands = $operands

Write-S3LifecycleConfiguration -BucketName test-bla -Configuration_Rule $NewRule
```